# why is my connection object suddenly a cursor object in the main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

PyMySQL==0.9.2
python 3.6.4
I simplified my code a little, it is supposed to run on many sql databases. My current struggle is with pymysql and mysql.
main:
$>cat testje.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pymysql as dbdr
from dbconnections import mysql as dbc

with dbc.connect(dbdr) as conn:
    print(conn)
```

$>cat dbconnections/mysql.py

```
def connect(db):
    dbc = db.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='cistats', password='bloemkool',
                      db='mysql', port=int(3306)
                    #  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
                    )
    print(dbc)
    return dbc
```

output:
$>./testje.py

```
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x10a72e5c0>
<pymysql.cursors.Cursor object at 0x10b16cfd0>
```

It shows that in the connect function dbc is a Connection object.
Why is it magically appearing as Cursor object in main?
How can I fix this? In main I really am expecting a Connection object.

The same structure is working ok for cx_Oracle, psycopg2 and pytds drivers.

Comment: Because `with` is invoking `dbc.connect().__enter__()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I see it returns self.cursor() instead of just self like the other drivers do. Looks like strange behaviour to me. So I can change the code by stripping the 'with' construction. Do I have other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentioned, the cause is that when using `with` the connect().**enter**() is called. This is the same for other drivers but the other drivers just have:

```
def __enter__(self):
            return self
```

and pymysql has:

```
def __enter__(self):
    """Context manager that returns a Cursor"""
    return self.cursor()
```

So I changed my code to simply: `conn = dbc.connect(...)` and now it works for all driver I have used so far.